My nextJS app won't load the UPLOADTHING_SECRET from my ".env.loca"l file
This is the code snippet for my .env.local config:
UPLOADTHING_SECRET=sk_live_c7155.......

UPLOADTHING_APP_ID=igwu....

NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL='http://localhost:3000/'

I am trying to upload images for my application to UploadThing in my local server. The API code snippet for core.js is as below, but when I hit the API, I am getting:
This error
UPLOADTHING_SECRET: undefined ⨯ UPLOADTHING 12:16:18 PM No secret provided
Here’s the code for my core.js at the api/core.js:
import { createUploadthing } from "uploadthing/next";

console.log("UPLOADTHING_SECRET:", process.env.UPLOADTHING_SECRET);

const f = createUploadthing();

export const ourFileRouter = { categoryimageUploader: f({ image: { maxFileSize: "1MB" } }) .onUploadComplete(async ({ metadata, file }) => { console.log("file url", file.url, metadata);

return { uploadedBy: "Dan K" }; }),

};

I tried logging the .env.local files but it is like the app is not reading any configs from my .env.local file.

Are you using the pages or app router?

Please double-check that you've followed the docs https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables - it does look like you have
